# Facebook SDK, fetching friends

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently building an app, and I need to fetch all the friends of a user, in order to display them to that specific user (public picture + name).

I have tried to implement the `taggable_friend` into my app in order to do so, but Facebook is not giving me the permission to use it as they say it should only be used to tag friends in stories.

Also, my question is, how apps like "Tinder" and "Hot or Not" do to get access to my entire friend list (even the one not using the app)?

And in the case of "Hot or Not", they even display my friends not using the app so that if I like them, I can invite them to join.

Comment: Tinder and Hot or Not is using API v1.0 will stop working at 4/30/2015 for them.

Answer (score 2):

In the v2.0 release on the Facebook Graph API, the ability to access a person's friends was changed in two ways. The first was via a new permission:

> Friend list is no longer part of the default permission set and has
>   its own permission: Asking for access to a person's friend list is now
>   a separate permission that your app must request. The new permission
>   is called user_friends.

The second affected which people are returned when requesting the list of friends:

> Friend list now only returns friends who also use your app: The list
>   of friends returned via the /me/friends endpoint is now limited to the
>   list of friends that have authorized your app.

You can find more information here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your answer. I read the link already but it is really ambiguous because they tell you in the doc that you user_friend is a new permission you must ask for : - Friend list is no longer part of the default permission set and has its own permission: Asking for access to a person's friend list is now a separate permission that your app must request. The new permission is called user_friends. But then they tell you further below that user_friend only return friends that also use the app. So it does not seem to be different than friend_list that doesn't need authorization...

Comment: requesting a permission in this context I means you need to create a submission in order to use this on non-app developers. You can do this by going to http://developers.facebook.com/apps selecting your > Status & Review > Start Submission

Comment: Well I am not sure I am following you here. Because I don't understand which authorization I should ask for: everywhere I read that user_friends can be applied without submitting your app to Facebook but only retrieve the list of friends that also use your app. However, I need to be able to access the entire friendlist of any users. In that case, which authorization should I get?

Comment: you can never access the full friends list of a user. You can only access friends of a user who use your app.

Comment: Well thank you for answering. I however still think there is a way to do it as Tinder is able to fetch my entire friendlist, and Hor or not is able to display some of my friends from Facebook which are not using the app and ask me to invite them to join. And I am quiet sure they are using the new Facebook SDK as they have implemented this "function" in the last 2 months or so.

Comment: they will be using the old version of the API that will be deprecated shortly. Any app created after v2.0 of the API also cannot access this version.

Answer (score 1):

I tested a lot Facebook API this year, and Facebook won't let you see your friends, for security matters, **they only let you see the ones registered in the same app**. If you are seeing the ones that are not, probably Tinder or whatever app is not using the latest version, v1.0 i guess, that will expire on April 30th, 2015.